# JavaScript setting dates in textboxes not consistent

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a couple of textboxes where a user set a from date and to date from a button click which adds 7 days or substracts 7 to whatever is the current value in each box.

When the page is first loaded the dates that are added into the textboxes are based upon the user belonging to a group. Thus if a user belongs to group A, the from date is a Sunday, but if the user belongs to group B it is a Friday. This logic I set in the page load event in my ASP.Net page.

The situation that is baffling me, is whilst I can set the dates, and get my JavaScript to work with group A, if a switch the user to group B, and click on a button rather expecting the date in from changing from 17th January 10th January, it jumps to 29th December 2014. It seems to be getting a completely differently value initially 5th January 2015.

The JavaScript I have is:

```
var fromDateIn = new Date(formatDate(document.getElementById('<%=txtFromDate.ClientID%>').value));
var newfromdate = new Date(fromDateIn);
```

In one of the button event, I have:

```
function setNewFromDate() {
    newfromdate.setDate(newfromdate.getDate() - 7);
    document.getElementById('<%= txtFromDate.ClientID%>').value = formatDate(newfromdate);
    var toDate = new Date(newfromdate);
    document.getElementById('<%= txtToDate.ClientID%>').value = formatDate(toDate.setDate(toDate.getDate() + 6));
}
```

As I say, everything works perfectly and I get the right dates when the user is one group, but as soon I change the user to another group and set the initial from and to dates, I get this problem. Can anyone please advise I can get consistency in this?

Thanks

Comment: you should try using momentjs to do your date and time stuff. Helps with all the edge cases.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the variable values in a debugger? Are you sure that `formatDate()` produces a value that can be correctly converted to a Date object? I would suspect that `fromDateIn` doesn't have the value you're expecting and that it's throwing everything else off. Have you verified that your `formatDate()` function (which you haven't shown us, BTW) is designed to handle a millisecond value input?

Comment: I did just that with an alert() box and this is where I saw 5/01/2015, but in the textbox it shows 17/01/2014. So I cannot see where the new value has come from

Comment: Well there's the problem - `new Date("17/01/2014")` will create a date that is [year 2014] [+ 17 months] [+ 1 day]. That results in May 1, 2015. You should be using the `new Date(year, month, day)` constructor after determining what each of those values is.

Comment: It is nothing to do with the formatting of the date. I have set the code to display the date with the user group that works and this always shows the correct date. When I change to the new group and hard code in the date 17th January it says 5th January on load of the page. It is though the date is not being found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with the way you are instantiating `fromDateIn`. You are passing it a value in the format `dd/MM/yyyy`, but the date constructor that takes a single string value is locale dependent and is treating the input as `MM/dd/yyyy`. This results in a completely bogus value for `fromDateIn` that throws everything else off.

You should find a way to determine the year, month and day for the start date (either by parsing it out of the textbox value or having the ASPX logic stuff it into the page somehow). And instantiate the date using the `new Date(year, month, day)` constructor. (This requires bearing in mind that `month` is 0-based [i.e. January = 0, February = 1]).

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
newfromdate.setDate(newfromdate.getDate() - 7)
```

Looks like you're trying to move back a week.  This will fail.  setDate changes only the Day of Month.  Can you guess what happens when Day of Month is less than 7?

Comment: It will do what he expects it to do - move the date back by 7 days.

Comment: JLRishe is right getDate()-7 moves back a week at a time, and the method handles the month. And if you read my question, this setup works fine. I cannot see what the difference is by changing the user to a new group